# Automated indentation cleaner for MATLAB or Octave?

Tags: matlab, coding-style, indentation, octave, auto-indent

Does anyone know of an existing method of automatically cleaning the indentation of a MATLAB/Octave script? I've got someone else's code (no, really!), and it's horrible - none of the loops or functions are indented, and half of the other lines are indented to apparently random depths.

The problem with MATLAB is that it doesn't use braces, so C++ style indenters aren't going to work. Python ones might, with a bit of modification, which I will try if I can't find a pre-existing solution.

Basically it'd just need to indent lines after lines starting with `function`, `for`, `if`, `while`... and un-indent lines starting with `end*`, I think...

**Clarification:** As pointed out by Jonas, MATLAB users can just select all, and `ctrl+I` to nicify the indentation. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the MATLAB editor, and it would also be nice to be able to auto-indent a batch of files all at once.

Comment: maybe some pascal indenter then?

Comment: You can use online services like a [MATLAB Code Beautifier](http://base-n.de/matlab/code_beautifier.html)

Comment: Please see my answer regarding [MBeautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960822/how-can-i-reformat-code-in-matlab-editor/37362250#37362250)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CTRL+A` (to select all), followed by `CTRL+I` (to automatically indent) will do the trick in the Matlab editor.

Comment: You get a vote up for that one, cause technically, it answers the question. Unfortunately, I'm actually using octave, so I don't have the matlab editor.

Comment: @naught101: Thanks for the upvote. Would something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21798-editing-matlab-files-in-vim) help?

Comment: Emacs with octave-mode can do it. Emacs or Vim (as said by Jonas) + macros can do it on batch (you don't have to open manually all your files).

Comment: There is an emacs [matlab-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/MatlabMode) as well that you may use :)

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I should have known emacs and vi would have answers. I really should learn one of them. Anyway, I got frustrated with the work I was doing, and wrote this as a displacement activity. Remove the `+ '.test.m'` to replace files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, sys

def startswith(line=""):
    # these need some word-boundary condition, but \b isn't working
    ctrlstart = '\s*(function|if|while|for|switch)'
    ctrlcont = '\s*(elseif|else|case|catch|otherwise)'
    ctrlend = '\s*(end|endfunction|endif|endwhile|endfor|endswitch)'
    match = re.match(ctrlstart, line)
    if ( match != None ) :
        return ['start',  match.group(0)]
    match=re.match(ctrlcont, line) 
    if ( match!=None ) :
        return ['cont',  match.group(0)]
    match=re.match(ctrlend, line)
    if ( match!=None ) :
        return ['end',  match.group(0)]
    else :
        return [False,  None]

def main( filelist = list() ) :
    for filename in filelist:
        nextindent = 0
        indentmult = 2
        file = open(filename, 'r')
        filelines = file.readlines()
        for ind in range(0, len(filelines)) :
            indentlevel = nextindent
            match = startswith(filelines[ind])
            if match[0] == 'start' :
                nextindent += 1
            elif match[0] == 'cont' :
                indentlevel -= 1
            elif match[0] == 'end' :
                indentlevel -= 1
                nextindent -= 1
            elif match[0] == False :
                nextindent = indentlevel
            filelines[ind] = ' '*indentlevel*indentmult + filelines[ind].lstrip().rstrip() +'\n'
        outfile = open(filename + '.test.m', 'w')
        outfile.writelines(filelines)
        file.close()
        outfile.close()

args = []
for arg in sys.argv[1:] :
    args += [str(arg)]
main(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the emacs way but it doesn't work, i am new to ubuntu and octave. So i took the easiest way :D, online site that indent the code for me and i can copy/paste the new clean code.

http://base-n.de/matlab/code_beautifier.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is a vim plugin to automatically indent and syntax highlight for octave code

https://github.com/tranvansang/octave.vim