# How to auto-indent/-format matrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, ide, auto-indent

I'm looking for a way to make my `Matlab code` more readable.

I know the **Auto-Indent** feature `(select code, hit Ctrl+i)`, but unfortunately this does not **"beautify"** matrices.

**Example:**

```
J = [j11,j12,       j13,    j14;
     j21,    j22,        j23,j24;
     j31,     j32,        j33,        j34;
     j41,       j42,j43,       j44];
```

Now, I would like this messy matrix to look something like this - every element should be aligned, like in a `table`, independent of the length of the elements:

```
J = [j11,        j12,        j13,        j14;
     j21,        j22,        j23,        j24;
     j31,        j32,        j33,        j34;
     j41,        j42,        j43,        j44];
```

The spacing should automatically be large enough so every element fits in. (In this example it certainly is a bit large.)

Do you guys know any way to do that?

Comment: Read [DVarga's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37362250/5698672) in the duplicate target. That does what you're looking for.

Comment: Try clean the code by deleting double spaces..

Comment: Thanks @SardarUsama that does exactly what I was looking for